# jQuery fire a function after set amount of pixels is scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to fire a function after set amount of pixels (500 px) is scrolled.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scrollPosition >= 500) {
      console.log("function hit");
    }
  });
});
```

This code will fire the function on each scroll after 500px is reached. What I am trying to achieve is to run a function after each 500px is reached (after 500px then 1000px etc). Is the scroll function even a good choice?

Comment: You could reset the scrollPosition variable to 0 after each 500px movement. This may require coming up with a plan for when they scroll back up and then down again.

Comment: Or add 500 to the number each time it's passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var targetPosition = 500;

    var onScroll = function () {
        scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
        console.log(scrollPosition);
        if (scrollPosition >= targetPosition) {
            console.log("function hit");
            targetPosition += 500;
        }
    }

    $(window).on('scroll', onScroll);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use modulo operator to find remainder on dividing scrollposition variable with 500 . remainder value will be '0' for every 
 500px

i have used 50 to demonstrate

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
    
    if ( scrollPosition%50 ==0) {
      console.log("function hit");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```